# What is better solution, to keep test data in feature file with scenarios or in seperate files (xml, json, yml) when using Cucumber Java?

Tags: cucumber

According to me, keeping it with scenarios make more sense because of following
1. We can use same scenarios steps with different data set. 
2. Readability also increase if we specify them in feature file.
3. Cucumber as already given functionality of test data management

But in all my previous company framework, test data was kept in separate files.

Please let me know what is best way.

Answer (score 0):

Below are some of the factors that will decides whether we should use `data table`/`examples` or external data files.

1. Number of columns
2. Is data static/dynamic
3. source of data

Let's discuss each of the above.

**1. Number of Columns:** 
It would be ideal to pass the data from feature file, when you have less than 10 columns. But having more than 10 columns make it harder to read the scenario. More the columns, more complex to read and maintain (error prone). In that case having the data in external file makes it easy.

**2.Is data Static/Dynamic:**
If you are sure that the data is static meaning you don't have to change the data often then you can stick to feature file. But consider the scenario, where your data will change every time (eg: if you want to place 100 orders and then wait for some time and want to check the status of each order based on OrderID. In this case you better store the order ids' in an external file and pull them as part other validation feature(s)).

**3. source of data**
If you are sure that data will be filled/updated by the people who have access to the feature files you can use feature files. But, consider the case where the test data will be filled by the external team/ external source (like data base) then it's better to maintain it separate by that way you can get the file and replace it when there is a newer version. (make sure to provide the template in this case, so that job would be easy for the external team and you when filling the data).

There might be other cases that will decide the right place for your test data, but those are the 3 points that I have on top of my head.